# Duality Theorem - Optimal solution of both Primal and Dual

Tags: duality-theorems, simplex, operations-research, two-phase-simplex

The Duality Theorem, in short, states that the optimal value of the Primal (P) and Dual (D) Linear Programs are the same if the solution, of either, is a basic feasible solution.

My question is that it also follows that (from Linear and Nonlinear Programming - Luenberger, Ye), from a corollary to the Weak Duality Lemma

$$\mathbf{c}^{T}\mathbf{x}_{*} = \mathbf{y}_{*}^{T}\mathbf{b},$$

where $\mathbf{x}_{*}$ and $\mathbf{y}_{*}^{T}$ are the optimal feasible solutions, and so we can always find the optimal solutions to the (P) and (D) given that we just find one? Am I interpreting this correctly?

For example, suppose I have the following (P) problem:

$$\text{max}~~~3x_1 - x_2 - x_3 + x_4$$
$$\text{subject to}~~~x_1 + 2x_2 - 4x_3 +x_4 = 3$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~2x_1 - 2x_2 + 3x_3 + 3x_4 = 9$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 - x_4 = 6$$
$$x_i \ge 0, \forall i$$

Solving (by two-phase simplex) gives an optimal value of -5 and an optimal solution of 
$\mathbf{x} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
2 \\
3 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$

But then the optimal solution to the (D) is just the optimal solution to 
$$-5 = 3y_1 + 9y_2 + 6y_3,$$

which we find by $\mathbf{y}_{*}^T = \mathbf{c}^TB^{-1}$. We have $\mathbf{c}^T = \begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
-3 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$
and $B^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & 1 & -\frac{4}{3} \\
0 & -1 & 2 \\
\frac{1}{3} & -1 & \frac{5}{3} 
\end{pmatrix}$, from the last iteration of the two-phase method. Then $\mathbf{y}_{*}^T = \mathbf{c}^TB^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{2}{3} & 7 & -\frac{35}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$, which yields $-5$ as the optimal value for the (D) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  That's precisely the statement of the Strong Duality Theorem, which asserts

1. the existence of $\mathbf{y}_{*}$ provided that of $\mathbf{x}_{*}$ (and vice versa)
2. the zero duality gap $\mathbf{y}_{*}^{T}\mathbf{b} -
    \mathbf{c}^{T}\mathbf{x}_{*}$ is zero provided the existence of $\mathbf{x}_{*}$ or $\mathbf{y}_{*}$

Both the primal and the dual LP in your numerical example yield the *same* objective value.  This is a consequence of the Strong Duality Theorem once you showed the existence of $\mathbf{x}_{*}$ in $(P)$ (by two-phase simplex method).

In practice, once you have computed $\mathbf{x}_{*}$, you can use [Complementary Slackness condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Complementary_slackness) to find $\mathbf{y}_{*}$.